# ларавель обновление фото

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6

есть такой метод, он отрабатывает и сохраняет фото, но при return возвращает старое фото, и на странице новое не появляется до тех пор пока не нажмешь ctrl+f5

```
public function edit(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
             'phone' => 'required|min:11'
        ]);
        if ($request->hasFile('newphoto')) {
            $destinationPath = 'img/avatars/';
            $fileName = Auth::user()->id . '.jpg';
            $request->file('newphoto')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
            $photo  = $destinationPath . $fileName;
        }else $photo = Auth::user()->attributes->photo;

        $attributes = UsersAttributes::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                                        ->update(['username' => $request->username,
                                            'birthday' => $request->birthday, 'gender' => $request->gender,
                                            'city' => $request->city, 'phone' => $request->phone, 'pay' => $request->pay, 'photo' => $photo]);

        return view('profile.profile')->with(['profile' => Auth::user()]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Адрес файла всегда одинаковый, поэтому браузер кэширует запрос.

У вас адрес аватарки всегда вида `site.com/img/avatars/12.jpg`

Добавьте случайный значение в адрес, чтобы измежать получение прошлой аватарки, кеширование останется, но не будет получние старой аватарки:

```
$photo  = $destinationPath . $fileName . '?' . rand();
```